# can't figure out why this class isn't working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.social-links {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
}
.social-links li a:hover,
.social-links li a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}
.social-links .nav li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
.phone{
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
 <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<div class="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
             
            <ul class="social-links list-inline">
            <li><a class="fa fa-facebook text-primary"></a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-twitter text-primary"></a></li>        
            <li><a class="fa fa-instagram text-primary"></a></li>
            <li><a class="fa fa-linkedin text-primary"></a></li>
            </ul>
           
            <ul class="phone list-inline">
            <li><a class="fa fa-phone text-primary"></a></li>
            
            </ul>
                    
     
</div>
```

trying to make the icons inline and float phone to  the right in bootstrap but i can't get it to work i dont know why i can't get the classes to work the only way that it works if i use style="" inside the ul

Comment: You don't include Bootstrap in your example, so Bootstrap's classes won't work.

Comment: i didn't but .pull-right .pull-left  worked  while i couldn't figure out while float didn't work

Comment: Why are you not using bootstrap's nav?

Comment: i have a navbar working fine just below this top-bar... i just wanted to customize this one but class didn't wont to work in the ul so i tried the id didn't wont to work as well

Comment: seems phone class wasnt getting applied. i formatted the question, is this what you were expecting?  Made a fiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/7k22wrst/